# Number of problems a student knows on an exam given the conditional probability of the student knowing the answer given the answer is correct.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A student takes an examination consisting of $20$ true-false questions. The
student knows the answer to $N$ of the questions, which are answered correctly,
and guesses the answers to the rest. The conditional probability that the
student knows the answer to a question, given that the student answered it
correctly, is $0.824$. Calculate $N$.

---

I first set up the conditional probability as $$P(K \vert C) = 0.824 = \frac{P(C \vert K) \cdot P(K)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(K)}{P(C)} $$ Where, obviously $P(C \vert K) = 1$

I need to know $P(K) $ and $P(C)$. I believe $P(K)$ to just be $\frac{N}{20}$ since $N$ is the *number* of questions the student knows and there are $20$ questions total. Now I want to know $P(C)$ or the probability that the student gets a question correct.

Initially I formulated this as $P(C) = \frac{(20-N)}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$. Where the first term gives us the probability that a question is a guess and then the probability of getting that question correct ($50$% for a T-F exam). However, this was incorrect.

I tried amending my formula for $P(C)$ by taking more of a "Law of Total Probability" approach to it and tried out $P(C) = [20-N] \cdot \frac{1}{2} + N \cdot 1$ where the first term is the number of problems guessed times the probability of getting a guess correct and the second term is the number of questions known times the probability of getting a known question correct. This too was incorrect.

So my question is **how do I approach figuring out what P(C) is?**

Answer (score 2):

Your law of total probability approach is the way to go.  We know that $\Pr[C \mid K] = 1$, and $\Pr[K] = N/20$.  So

$$\Pr[C] = \Pr[C \mid K]\Pr[K] + \Pr[C \mid \bar K]\Pr[\bar K],$$

where $\bar K$ is the complementary event of not knowing the answer to a randomly selected question; hence $\Pr[\bar K] = 1 - N/20$.  The only quantity remaining is $\Pr[C \mid \bar K]$, the probability of answering a randomly selected question given that the student doesn't know the answer.  As this is a true-false question with only two options, this probability is $1/2$.  So

$$\Pr[C] = \frac{N}{20} + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{N}{20}\right).$$  It follows that
$$0.824 = \Pr[K \mid C] = \frac{\frac{N}{20}}{\frac{N}{20} + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{N}{20}\right)} = \frac{2N}{N + 20},$$ from which we obtain $N = 14.0136$, and the most reasonable integer value is $N = 14$.  Substituting this into the formula yields $\Pr[K \mid C] = \frac{14}{17} \approx 0.823529,$ which is $0.824$ when rounded to three digits.